# AUTO_INCREMENT на 9 знаков

Tags: mysql

Ситуация такая, нужно чтобы нумерация AUTO_INCREMENT в базе MYSQL начиналась не с 1, а с 000 000 001. Может кто-нибудь знает как это можно реализовать в MYSQL или на PHP, так чтобы знаков было 9 при выводе пользователю?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Это не нужно. Используйте printf("%09d", $value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT(9) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL), (0), (DEFAULT);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> |        id |
> | --------: |
> | 000000001 |
> | 000000002 |
> | 000000003 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=326664475edcaf42b3fd9f865e49f139)*

PS. ZEROFILL объявлен deprecated, и в любой момент, в любой очередной версии, может помереть.

Comment: В принципе мне знакомые подсказали, что можно сделать через str_pad на php, но надеюсь кому-то оба решения пригодятся. Спасибо.